# Changing size of image referred to in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I want to know if it is possible to change the size of an image referred to in an anchor tag. I am using media queries, and once the device width goes below 481px, I want the image displayed when you click on the a-tag to be a certain size smaller than the original one...The image pops out in a jquery lightbox function...

```
<a href"/images/originalImage.jpg">Image 1</a>
```

How would one change size of `originalImage.jpg`? With either CSS or JS... CSS preferably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of 2 solutions:

1. **JavaScript:** Simply change the `href` attribute of the anchor tag depending on the size of the screen.
2. **CSS:** Have 2 anchor tags with the 2 different images and show/hide 1 of them at a time depending on the media queries.

Comment: thank you for your answer...That is an idea, but I was ideally looking for a solution where I didn't have to create 2 different images, hence less server disk space used...but if that is the only way, I guess that should do... I though there might be another property I don't know about. I believe the css is a better method? what do you suggest? some people has javascript turned off